# crazy output from tools package write_PACKAGES function

Tags: r

I am using `write_PACKAGES` function from tools package to create a PACKAGES.txt file for my custom repository.

EX:

```
# File system folder path where i have zipfiles of my local repo packages 
repo_path<-"C:/Users/currentmini"
library(tools)
write_PACKAGES(dir = paste(repo_path, "/bin/windows/contrib/3.3", sep=''),
               type = "win.binary")
```

If I run above commands in RStudio, output "PACKAGES.txt" file is coming out some times with lower case package names on top `"Ex: abind"` and some times is putting upper case alphabet package names on top `"Ex: Amelia"` , and messing up my package listing order.

Because of this inconsistency , I am unable to use beyond compare or any other folder comparison tools when ever I updated my local package repository.

Does anybody know of any way to tell `write_PACKAGES` function or any R global setting to influence sorting order for package names?

1st attempt package.txt file snapshot below:

```
Package: abind
Version: 1.4-3
Depends: R (>= 1.5.0)
License: LGPL (>= 2)

Package: acepack
Version: 1.3-3.3
License: MIT + file LICENSE
Archs: i386, x64
```

2st attempt package.txt file snapshot below:

```
Package: Amelia
Version: 1.7.4
Depends: R (>= 3.0.2), Rcpp (>= 0.11)
Imports: foreign, utils, grDevices, graphics, methods, stats
LinkingTo: Rcpp (>= 0.11), RcppArmadillo
Suggests: tcltk, Zelig
License: GPL (>= 2)
Archs: i386, x64

Package: BH
Version: 1.60.0-1
License: BSL-1.0
```

Comment: Looks like you were using the C locale in the 2nd attempt, and some natural language locale in the first attempt.  Use `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")` to always use the C locale.

Comment: That works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`tools::write_PACKAGES` uses the collation order defined for the current locale.  The first example looks like a typical English collation order (or many others), while the second is the C collation order.

To always get the same ordering, you need to keep the collation order the same every time.  This code would force the C collation order always:

```
save <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
tools::write_PACKAGES(dir = paste(repo_path, "/bin/windows/contrib/3.3", sep=''),
           type = "win.binary")
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", save)
```